# How to resize website for 1080x1920 Mobile and Monitor?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to resize my webpage in css using the @media query for both monitor and mobile. However, my mobile is 1080x1920 and so is my monitor. So when I use the media query, my mobile inherits my monitor's css.

How do you distinguish from the two?

Thanks.

Comment: What mobile are you using? Unless it's massive, it won't be the same.

Comment: I'm using a BLU Vivo 5r, its resolution is the same as my monitor.

Comment: If it's a High-DPI display, maybe it has that many physical pixels, yes. But the logical resolution should be lower than that.

Comment: but.. shure your phone i 1920px wide?! what i can find your phone has 720 x 1280.?

Comment: Can you use it's DPI as a metric in the @media query?

Comment: @Kalabalik what you found is the Vivo 5. The Vivo 5R, however, does have 1080p: "[_The BLU Vivo 5R now has an improved resolution utilizing a vivid Full HD 1080p display_](http://bluproducts.com/news/2016-vivo-5r-release.html)"

Comment: @media(max-width: 480px){} isn´t used for resolution, its used for device width instead. while you are right that smartphones have 1920x1080px resolution, they wont have such a width, most of mobile phones fall into 320-480px

Comment: are you sure you have the viewport meta tag in your markup?

Answer (score 4):

It's sounds as if your phone is zooming out to display the full website.

Have you got a "responsive meta tag" on the page? This should go in the `<head></head>` of your page.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

It tells the browser to match the media query pixels to your devices actual width, and not it's pixel count.